Is it possible to read file data for use in Vitest tests of Cloudflare Workers?
I have a Cloudflare Worker that interacts with an R2 bucket containing several data files. I want to write tests for this, but since Vitest isolates the tests from the development bucket, I need to be able to programmatically add the data files to the R2 bucket before each test. Further, the data that I want to test against is in a JSON files that I would also need to read in to memory. The problem I am having is that I cannot use 'import' or 'require' in order to do this. Is there a work around? Perhaps a way to use the development bucket for the tests instead?
I have tried to use 'import' and 'require' syntax. I have also tried to configure 'setupFiles' in Vitest to load the data to global. In all cases I get "Error: require() is not yet implemented in Workers."
